# strange behavior for accessing the return value in a destructor in c++?

Tags: c++, c++11

here is the code:

expected behavior: `In ~X() the ptr shoule be != nil no matter the IS_ERR macro is defined or not`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

struct X {
    X(std::function<void()> f): f_{std::move(f)} {}

    ~X() {
        f_();
    }

    std::function<void()> f_;
};

std::shared_ptr<int> func() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;

    X x([&] {
        std::cout << "dtor, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
    });

    if (ptr = std::make_shared<int>(100)) {
        std::cout << "return, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
        return ptr;
    }

#if defined(IS_ERR)
    return nullptr;
    // return, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732821766368
    // dtor, ptr == null? 1, addr 140732821766368 // ATTENTION: ptr == nil here !!!! the internal of ptr is moved to the caller before the destructor of X is executed even if there is no receiver in the caller. 
    // fini, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732821766576
#else
    // return, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732879315376
    // dtor, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732879315376 // ATTENTION ptr != nil  the expected behavior
    // fini, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732879315376
    return ptr;
#endif
}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = func();
    std::cout << "fini, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
}
```

- in the defined(IS_ERR)

// ATTENTION: ptr == nil here !!!! the internal of ptr is moved to the caller before the destructor of X is executed even if there is no receiver in the caller.

- in the no defined(IS_ERR)

// ATTENTION ptr != nil  the expected behavior

- the code is tested under followings enviornments:

```
g++ --version : g++ (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
```

the test result is the same:

```
rm -f test && clang++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor    
dtor, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732827398560
rm -f test && clang++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11    -DIS_ERR  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor   
dtor, ptr == null? 1, addr 140732832612560
rm -f test && clang++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11 -O3  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 0, addr 140732887884168
rm -f test && clang++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11  -O3  -DIS_ERR  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 1, addr 140732702822624
```

```
rm -f test && g++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 0, addr 140735881081728
rm -f test && g++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11    -DIS_ERR  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 1, addr 140722084209920
rm -f test && g++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11 -O3  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 0, addr 140736717254624
rm -f test && g++ -o test test.cc -std=c++11  -O3  -DIS_ERR  -Wno-parentheses && ./test | grep dtor
dtor, ptr == null? 1, addr 140735485800352
```

- the use case of the example code is as follows:

```cpp
using Error = std::shared_ptr<std::string>;
// go style error propagation is simulated here

Error func() {
  Error err;
 
    X x([&] {
        if (err) {
          // ATTENTION: we may do something here, like logging, alerting
        } else {
         // or we any do something REALLY REALLY IMPORTANT here, like express, transferring money ... it may cause catastrophic result ... (it is actually err != nil, but you think the result is ok ...) 
        }
    });
 err = doSomeThing()
if (err) {
  err = Wrap(err, "do func");
  return err;
}
#if defined(IS_ERR)
  return nullptr;
#else
  return err;
#endif
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<int> func() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;

    X x([&] {
        std::cout << "dtor, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
    });

    if (ptr = std::make_shared<int>(100)) {
        std::cout << "return, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
        return ptr;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

The line `return ptr;` [automatically moves from `ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return#Automatic_move_from_local_variables_and_parameters) (so is equivalent to `return std::move(ptr);`). This means it is moved from to construct the return value, before the destructor of `X x` is called, so the `ptr` it refers to is now empty.

The second variant without `-DIS_ERR`:

```
std::shared_ptr<int> func() {
    std::shared_ptr<int> ptr;

    X x([&] {
        std::cout << "dtor, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
    });

    if (ptr = std::make_shared<int>(100)) {
        std::cout << "return, ptr == null? " << (ptr == nullptr) << ", addr " << (long long)(&ptr) << std::endl;
        return ptr;
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

The function `func` can now employ [named return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision#Non-mandatory_elision_of_copy.2Fmove_.28since_C.2B.2B11.29_operations) (NRVO), since it always returns `ptr`. This means that the local variable `ptr` can be constructed directly in the return value (the `auto ptr` in the main function). The lambda in `x` captures the same object as the `ptr` in the main function, so it won't be moved from like in the previous case.

The easy fix is to capture by value in `x`. Otherwise, you can disable NRVO by returning `std::as_const(ptr)` so it can't be moved from.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you're seeing the effect of [Named Return Value Optimizaion](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2016/11/28/return-value-optimizations/)

When the expression in a `return` expression is the last use of a named local variable, the compiler is permitted to optimize the return by turning the copy into a move.  Arguably, since the lambda captures `ptr` by reference, the compiler really has no way of knowing that the return in the if is not in fact the last reference (the lambda will access it when X is destroyed), so perhaps NRVO should not be allowed here.  But your compiler is doing it anyways.

When IS_ERR is not defined, there is clearly another reference to `ptr` after the one in the if, so NRVO is not done (at least for the return in the if -- the one at the end of the function probably gets NRVO)

The 'ptr == null' you're seeing is because the lambda is accessing the `ptr` after it has been moved from, not after it has been destroyed.